# Visual Studio Database Project using linked server database reference

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, linked-server, database-project

I am trying to use a linked Server database reference in a Visual Studio 2013 (using SQLServer 2008) project.

I am able to get it to build by making another project with the references as outlined
in this link:

[[Do I need a database reference for a linked server in a SQL Server database project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635244/do-i-need-a-database-reference-for-a-linked-server-in-a-sql-server-database-proj][1])

But the project fails in the deploy step with the following error:
Error   474 SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, 
Procedure rs_ReportSubscriptions, Line 3 Could not find server 'TBSSRV07\TBSSQLDEVSRV' in 
    sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. 
    If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers. 
    For more information about this error, see the troubleshooting topics in the product documentation. 
    C:\tfs2010\EtracsDatabase\Etracs\bin\Debug\Etracs.sql

On the deployed server this is working (using a linked Server... Link : TBSSRV07\TBSSQLDEVSRV)

This is happening in a view creating script .. I have tried to add the sp_addLinkedServer
to the script...but in the deploy code my sp_addlinkedServer does not appear:

Here is the code for the view creation:

```
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'TBSSRV07', 
   @srvproduct=N'',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'TBSSRV07\TBSSQLDEVSRV';

GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rs_ReportSubscriptions] AS 
SELECT  C.Name ,
        CAST(ExtensionSettings AS XML).value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value)[1]',
                                             'varchar(250)') AS TargetSettingsTo ,
        CAST(ExtensionSettings AS XML).value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value)[2]',
                                             'varchar(250)') AS TargetSettingsCC ,

        LastStatus ,
        LastRunTime
FROM    [$(TBSSRV07)].[$(ReportServer)].dbo.Subscriptions AS S
        JOIN [$(TBSSRV07)].[$(ReportServer)].dbo.Catalog AS C ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
```

Here is the resultant script that is having a problem:

```
GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[rs_ReportSubscriptions]...';


GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rs_ReportSubscriptions] AS 
SELECT  C.Name ,
        CAST(ExtensionSettings AS XML).value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value)[1]',
                                             'varchar(250)') AS TargetSettingsTo ,
        CAST(ExtensionSettings AS XML).value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Value)[2]',
                                             'varchar(250)') AS TargetSettingsCC ,

        LastStatus ,
        LastRunTime
FROM    [$(TBSSRV07)].[$(ReportServer)].dbo.Subscriptions AS S
        JOIN [$(TBSSRV07)].[$(ReportServer)].dbo.Catalog AS C ON C.ItemID = S.Report_OID
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';
```

Finally here is the value that I used for in the database reference: 
:setvar TBSSRV07 "TBSSRV07\TBSSQLDEVSRV"

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? If so, please add your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "best" answer, but in this situation, I add a pre-deployment script to create the linked server, if it is not present.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.servers s WHERE s.[name] = N'$(TBSSRV07)' AND s.is_linked = 1)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver N'$(TBSSRV07)', ...
```